# Asymptote: when white isn't white

Tags: 3d, asymptote

I'm trying to display a white 3D ball with Asymptote (3D PDF), but it always turns up gray:

[image]

```
import graph3;
import solids;

defaultrender.merge=true;
size(10cm,0);

currentprojection=orthographic(-Z);

//currentlight=Headlamp;
//currentlight=light(-10,1,1);
//currentlight=White;
currentlight=Viewport;

draw(unitsphere,rgb(1,1,1));
```

I understand it's a lighting issue, and I've tried playing with its settings (the lines commented out in my source are some of my attempts), but I **never** manage to have white be white. If I understand correctly, **I need a whiter diffuse component in my light**, but I cannot see how to achieve that. And the documentation is not very clear…

---

This will be part of a molecular model, and the rendering I'm going for it something like this:

[image]

Comment: Check out the `material` in docs. You can try, for example:
`material surfpen;`
`surfpen.p=new pen[]{white,white,yellow,white};` 

`draw(unitsphere,surfpen);`

Comment: @g.kov: (off topic) Any chance you could throw in an answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151108/484)? Right now there isn't a viable candidate for the bounty, and I know you're at least as good at these things as I am.

Comment: @Charles Staats (off topic): I sincerely appreciate the offer and I'd like to, as I agree that a translation to `Asymptote` from `TikZ/PSTricks`
is not difficult in most cases,
but I can't promise, sorry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As `g.kov` suggests, you may be better off playing with the `material` rather than the lighting. In particular, ambient light tends to be rather subtle; you're better off using `emissivepen`, which essentially adds exactly that color to the entire sphere regardless of the lighting.

```
import three;

defaultrender.merge=true;
size(10cm,0);

currentprojection=orthographic(-Z);

draw(unitsphere, surfacepen=material(diffusepen=gray(0.5), emissivepen=gray(0.6), specularpen=black) );
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is probably going to be too white for you, but you can decrease `emissivepen` and `diffusepen` as needed. I enclose the code and a change in parameter `emissivepen` from `1.0` to `0.5` with step of `0.1`.

```
import settings;
outformat="eps";
// interactiveView=false;
// batchView=false;

import three;
size(200);
//currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,3);
//defaultrender=render(compression=Zero,merge=true);
currentlight.background=blue;
material White=material(diffusepen=gray(1.0),emissivepen=gray(1.0));
draw(unitsphere,White);
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 0):

`nolight` makes white is white!
`nolight` makes yellow is yellow!

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import three;
size(8cm,0);
draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),O--1.5X,Arrow3);
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),O--1.5Y,Arrow3);
draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),O--1.3Z,Arrow3);

//pen p=yellow+opacity(.9)+5pt;
pen p=white;

//draw(unitsphere,p);
draw(unitsphere,p,nolight);
```