# Plotting a knot on a torus

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Using `pgfplots`, I plotted a torus, with a knot that lies on its surface:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis equal image]

 \addplot3[domain=0:360, y domain=0:360, samples=20, surf, z buffer=sort]
 (
  {(2 + cos(x))*cos(y)},
  {(2 + cos(x))*sin(y)},
  {sin(x)}
 );

 \addplot3[domain=0:360, samples=50]
 (
 {(2 + cos(2*x))*cos(3*x)},
 {(2 + cos(2*x))*sin(3*x)},
 {sin(2*x)}
 );
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

However, it turns out that the knot is not shown properly, because parts of it that should be hidden by the surface, aren't. It should look something like this:

[image]

One of the first things I tried is putting in a `z buffer=sort` key for the knot's graph, however, this just screws up the curve. I guess the issue is that the torus and the knot have to somehow know about each other, for `z buffer=sort` to work, but there is no good way to do so.

Are there other approaches? I am open to trying non-`pgfplots` solutions.

Comment: With asymptote it should be straightforward. Are you also open to asymptote? I guess it would be slight modification of [the asymptote solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151203/121799) or [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151031/121799) might be even closer. I also think it is *possible* with `pgfplots`, but will require more work.

Comment: @marmot wow, this is awesome --- I have no idea what `asymptote` is, but I am about to learn!

Comment: Does that mean you do not want an answer because you want to try out yourself or that you are open to an asymptote answer. (Not that I have one in my pocket... ;-)

Comment: @marmot if you'd like to provide an answer, I would be happy to accept it! otherwise, I am in the process of understanding, and will provide a solution myself --- so its entirely up to your generosity!

Comment: Either way. (It is not generous to point to posts that solved a similar problem before, I think. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal but this is not really my proposal. It is a combination of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149759/121799) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149784/121799). Personally I like to use `asypictureB` by the author of the second answer. You can compile this e.g. with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document} % based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149759/121799 and
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149784/121799
\begin{asypicture}{name=torus}
import graph3;

size(200,0);
currentprojection=orthographic(4,0,2);

//inner radius
real R=2;
//outer radius
real a=0.75;

//surface:
triple f(pair t) {
  return ((R+a*cos(t.y))*cos(t.x),(R+a*cos(t.y))*sin(t.x),a*sin(t.y));
}

//path:
real x(real t) {return cos(t*3)*(R + a*cos(t));}
real y(real t) {return sin(t*3)*(R + a*cos(t));}
real z(real t) {return a*sin(t);}

pen p=blue+opacity(0.33);
// make surface and path
surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2pi,2pi),8,8,Spline);
path3 q=graph(x,y,z,0,6*pi,operator ..);

// draw surface and path
draw(s,surfacepen=material(diffusepen=blue+opacity(0.33), emissivepen=blue));
real linewidth = 2pt;
draw(q, p=linewidth + orange);
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one can also color different stretches of the path differently. Please let me know if there are problems, or if I should remove this answer because it does not represent any real progress compared to what is already on the market.