# Torus with lines winding along different axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I need to draw different types of lines winding the torus. But I am unable to generate it in the TikZ. I have the code, completely borrowed from the [very nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151031/120078) of Charles Staats. But the code is in asymptote not in usual TikZ (which I am familiar with). The look of the torus is exactly the way I want but I can't seem to reproduce it in the TikZ.

My question would be:
1. If the same quality image can be generated in Tikz?
2. If not then how it can be done in asymptote, how to compile it?
3. Is there a way to choose the number of smooth winding along any axis (major or minor) or both together.
Example to illustrate below---

Sorry for this trivial question, I tried a lot but with no success. The plot I want, looks like

(I.) winding twice along major axis: However, in the image the winding is not very smooth.

[image]

(II.) winding once along minor axis: But in the image the other side is dashed, instead if it could be made blur (to see the 3d contrast)

[image]

(III.) winding once along major and also once along minor axis: Sorry it is very poorly shown by me, that is because I couldn't achieve it through the code. Dash is showing that it is winding along the other facing side (which is in to the page)

[image]

Code is stolen from the [answer of Charles Staats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151031/120078)

```
    settings.outformat="pdf";

import graph3;
import contour;

// A bunch of auxiliary functions.

real fuzz = .001;

real umin(surface s) { return 0; }
real vmin(surface s) { return 0; }
pair uvmin(surface s) { return (umin(s), vmin(s)); }
real umax(surface s, real fuzz=fuzz) {
  if (s.ucyclic()) return s.index.length;
  else return s.index.length - fuzz;
}
real vmax(surface s, real fuzz=fuzz) {
  if (s.vcyclic()) return s.index[0].length;
  return s.index[0].length - fuzz;
}
pair uvmax(surface s, real fuzz=fuzz) { return (umax(s,fuzz), vmax(s,fuzz)); }

typedef real function(real, real);

function normalDot(surface s, triple eyedir(triple)) {
  real toreturn(real u, real v) {
    return dot(s.normal(u, v), eyedir(s.point(u,v)));
  }
  return toreturn;
}

struct patchWithCoords {
  patch p;
  real u;
  real v;
  void operator init(patch p, real u, real v) {
    this.p = p;
    this.u = u;
    this.v = v;
  }
  void operator init(surface s, real u, real v) {
    int U=floor(u);
    int V=floor(v);
    int index = (s.index.length == 0 ? U+V : s.index[U][V]);

    this.p = s.s[index];
    this.u = u-U;
    this.v = v-V;
  }
  triple partialu() {
    return p.partialu(u,v);
  }
  triple partialv() {
    return p.partialv(u,v);
  }
}

typedef triple paramsurface(pair);

paramsurface tangentplane(surface s, pair pt) {
  patchWithCoords thepatch = patchWithCoords(s, pt.x, pt.y);
  triple partialu = thepatch.partialu();
  triple partialv = thepatch.partialv();
  return new triple(pair tangentvector) {
    return s.point(pt.x, pt.y) + (tangentvector.x * partialu) + (tangentvector.y * partialv);
  };
}

guide[] normalpathuv(surface s, projection P = currentprojection, int n = ngraph) {
  triple eyedir(triple a);
  if (P.infinity) eyedir = new triple(triple) { return P.camera; };
  else eyedir = new triple(triple pt) { return P.camera - pt; };
  return contour(normalDot(s, eyedir), uvmin(s), uvmax(s), new real[] {0}, nx=n)[0];
}

path3 onSurface(surface s, path p) {
  triple f(int t) {
    pair point = point(p,t);
    return s.point(point.x, point.y);
  }

  guide3 toreturn = f(0);
  paramsurface thetangentplane = tangentplane(s, point(p,0));
  triple oldcontrol, newcontrol;
  int size = length(p);
  for (int i = 1; i <= size; ++i) {
    oldcontrol = thetangentplane(postcontrol(p,i-1) - point(p,i-1));
    thetangentplane = tangentplane(s, point(p,i));
    newcontrol = thetangentplane(precontrol(p, i) - point(p,i));
    toreturn = toreturn .. controls oldcontrol and newcontrol .. f(i);
  }

  if (cyclic(p)) toreturn = toreturn & cycle;

  return toreturn;

}

/*
 * This method returns an array of paths that trace out all the
 * points on s at which s is parallel to eyedir.
 */

path[] paramSilhouetteNoEdges(surface s, projection P = currentprojection, int n = ngraph) {
   guide[] uvpaths = normalpathuv(s, P, n);
  //Reduce the number of segments to conserve memory
  for (int i = 0; i < uvpaths.length; ++i) {
    real len = length(uvpaths[i]);
    uvpaths[i] = graph(new pair(real t) {return point(uvpaths[i],t);}, 0, len, n=n);
  }
  return uvpaths;
}   

private typedef real function2(real, real);
private typedef real function3(triple);

triple[] normalVectors(triple dir, triple surfacen) {
  dir = unit(dir);
  surfacen = unit(surfacen);
  triple v1, v2;
  int i = 0;
  do {
    v1 = unit(cross(dir, (unitrand(), unitrand(), unitrand())));
    v2 = unit(cross(dir, (unitrand(), unitrand(), unitrand())));
    ++i;
  } while ((abs(dot(v1,v2)) > Cos(10) || abs(dot(v1,surfacen)) > Cos(5) || abs(dot(v2,surfacen)) > Cos(5)) && i < 1000);
  if (i >= 1000) {
    write("problem: Unable to comply.");
    write(" dir = " + (string)dir);
    write(" surface normal = " + (string)surfacen);
  }
  return new triple[] {v1, v2};
}

function3 planeEqn(triple pt, triple normal) {
  return new real(triple r) {
    return dot(normal, r - pt);
  };
}

function2 pullback(function3 eqn, surface s) {
  return new real(real u, real v) {
    return eqn(s.point(u,v));
  };
}

/*
 * returns the distinct points in which the surface intersects
 * the line through the point pt in the direction dir
 */

triple[] intersectionPoints(surface s, pair parampt, triple dir) {
  triple pt = s.point(parampt.x, parampt.y);
  triple[] lineNormals = normalVectors(dir, s.normal(parampt.x, parampt.y));
  path[][] curves;
  for (triple n : lineNormals) {
    function3 planeEn = planeEqn(pt, n);
    function2 pullback = pullback(planeEn, s);
    guide[] contour = contour(pullback, uvmin(s), uvmax(s), new real[]{0})[0];

    curves.push(contour);
  }
  pair[] intersectionPoints;
  for (path c1 : curves[0])
    for (path c2 : curves[1])
      intersectionPoints.append(intersectionpoints(c1, c2));
  triple[] toreturn;
  for (pair P : intersectionPoints)
    toreturn.push(s.point(P.x, P.y));
  return toreturn;
}



/*
 * Returns those intersection points for which the vector from pt forms an
 * acute angle with dir.
 */
 int numPointsInDirection(surface s, pair parampt, triple dir, real fuzz=.05) {
  triple pt = s.point(parampt.x, parampt.y);
  dir = unit(dir);
  triple[] intersections = intersectionPoints(s, parampt, dir);
  int num = 0;
  for (triple isection: intersections)
    if (dot(isection - pt, dir) > fuzz) ++num;
  return num;
}

bool3 increasing(real t0, real t1) {
  if (t0 < t1) return true;
  if (t0 > t1) return false;
  return default;
}

int[] extremes(real[] f, bool cyclic = f.cyclic) {
  bool3 lastIncreasing;
  bool3 nextIncreasing;
  int max;
  if (cyclic) {
    lastIncreasing = increasing(f[-1], f[0]);
    max = f.length - 1;
  } else {
    max = f.length - 2;
    if (increasing(f[0], f[1])) lastIncreasing = false;
    else lastIncreasing = true;
  }
  int[] toreturn;
  for (int i = 0; i <= max; ++i) {
    nextIncreasing = increasing(f[i], f[i+1]);
    if (lastIncreasing != nextIncreasing) {
      toreturn.push(i);
    }
    lastIncreasing = nextIncreasing;
  }
  if (!cyclic) toreturn.push(f.length - 1);
  toreturn.cyclic = cyclic;
  return toreturn;
}

int[] extremes(path path, real f(pair) = new real(pair P) {return P.x;})
{
  real[] fvalues = new real[size(path)];
  for (int i = 0; i < fvalues.length; ++i) {
    fvalues[i] = f(point(path, i));
  }
  fvalues.cyclic = cyclic(path);
  int[] toreturn = extremes(fvalues);
  fvalues.delete();
  return toreturn;
}

path[] splitAtExtremes(path path, real f(pair) = new real(pair P) {return P.x;})
{
  int[] splittingTimes = extremes(path, f);
  path[] toreturn;
  if (cyclic(path)) toreturn.push(subpath(path, splittingTimes[-1], splittingTimes[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i+1 < splittingTimes.length; ++i) {
    toreturn.push(subpath(path, splittingTimes[i], splittingTimes[i+1]));
  }
  return toreturn;
}

path[] splitAtExtremes(path[] paths, real f(pair P) = new real(pair P) {return P.x;})
{
  path[] toreturn;
  for (path path : paths) {
    toreturn.append(splitAtExtremes(path, f));
  }
  return toreturn;
}

path3 toCamera(triple p, projection P=currentprojection, real fuzz = .01, real upperLimit = 100) {
  if (!P.infinity) {
    triple directionToCamera = unit(P.camera - p);
    triple startingPoint = p + fuzz*directionToCamera;
    return startingPoint -- P.camera;
  }
  else {
    triple directionToCamera = unit(P.camera);
    triple startingPoint = p + fuzz*directionToCamera;

    return startingPoint -- (p + upperLimit*directionToCamera);
  }
}

int numSheetsHiding(surface s, pair parampt, projection P = currentprojection) {
  triple p = s.point(parampt.x, parampt.y);
  path3 tocamera = toCamera(p, P);
  triple pt = beginpoint(tocamera);
  triple dir = endpoint(tocamera) - pt;
  return numPointsInDirection(s, parampt, dir);
}

struct coloredPath {
  path path;
  pen pen;
  void operator init(path path, pen p=currentpen) {
    this.path = path;
    this.pen = p;
  }
  /* draws the path with the pen having the specified weight (using colors)*/
  void draw(real weight) {
    draw(path, p=weight*pen + (1-weight)*white);
  }
}
coloredPath[][] layeredPaths;
// onTop indicates whether the path should be added at the top or bottom of the specified layer
void addPath(path path, pen p=currentpen, int layer, bool onTop=true) {
  coloredPath toAdd = coloredPath(path, p);
  if (layer >= layeredPaths.length) {
    layeredPaths[layer] = new coloredPath[] {toAdd};
  } else if (onTop) {
    layeredPaths[layer].push(toAdd);
  } else layeredPaths[layer].insert(0, toAdd);
}

void drawLayeredPaths() {
  for (int layer = layeredPaths.length - 1; layer >= 0; --layer) {
    real layerfactor = (1/3)^layer;
    for (coloredPath toDraw : layeredPaths[layer]) {
      toDraw.draw(layerfactor);
    }
  }
}

real[] cutTimes(path tocut, path[] knives) {
  real[] intersectionTimes = new real[] {0, length(tocut)};
  for (path knife : knives) {
    real[][] complexIntersections = intersections(tocut, knife);
    for (real[] times : complexIntersections) {
      intersectionTimes.push(times[0]);
    }
  }
  return sort(intersectionTimes);
}

path[] cut(path tocut, path[] knives) {
  real[] cutTimes = cutTimes(tocut, knives);
  path[] toreturn;
  for (int i = 0; i + 1 < cutTimes.length; ++i) {
    toreturn.push(subpath(tocut,cutTimes[i], cutTimes[i+1]));
  }
  return toreturn;
}

real[] condense(real[] values, real fuzz=.001) {
  values = sort(values);
  values.push(infinity);
  real previous = -infinity;
  real lastMin;
  real[] toReturn;
  for (real t : values) {
    if (t - fuzz > previous) {
      if (previous > -infinity) toReturn.push((lastMin + previous) / 2);
      lastMin = t;
    }
    previous = t;
  }
  return toReturn;
}

/*
 * A smooth surface parametrized by the domain [0,1] x [0,1]
 */
struct SmoothSurface {
  surface s;
  private real sumax;
  private real svmax;
  path[] paramSilhouette;
  path[] projectedSilhouette;
  projection theProjection;

  path3 onSurface(path paramPath) {
    return onSurface(s, scale(sumax,svmax)*paramPath);
  }

  triple point(real u, real v) { return s.point(sumax*u, svmax*v); }
  triple point(pair uv) { return point(uv.x, uv.y); }
  triple normal(real u, real v) { return s.normal(sumax*u, svmax*v); }
  triple normal(pair uv) { return normal(uv.x, uv.y); }

  void operator init(surface s, projection P=currentprojection) {
    this.s = s;
    this.sumax = umax(s);
    this.svmax = vmax(s);
    this.theProjection = P;
    this.paramSilhouette = scale(1/sumax, 1/svmax) * paramSilhouetteNoEdges(s,P);
    this.projectedSilhouette = sequence(new path(int i) {
    path3 truePath = onSurface(paramSilhouette[i]);
    path projectedPath = project(truePath, theProjection, ninterpolate=1);
    return projectedPath;
      }, paramSilhouette.length);
  }

  int numSheetsHiding(pair parampt) {
    return numSheetsHiding(s, scale(sumax,svmax)*parampt);
  }

  void drawSilhouette(pen p=currentpen, bool includePathsBehind=false, bool onTop = true) {
    int[][] extremes;
    for (path path : projectedSilhouette) {
      extremes.push(extremes(path));
    }

    path[] splitSilhouette;
    path[] paramSplitSilhouette;

    /*
     * First, split at extremes to ensure that there are no
     * self-intersections of any one subpath in the projected silhouette.
     */

    for (int j = 0; j < paramSilhouette.length; ++j) {
      path current = projectedSilhouette[j];

      path currentParam = paramSilhouette[j];

      int[] dividers = extremes[j];
      for (int i = 0; i + 1 < dividers.length; ++i) {
    int start = dividers[i];
    int end = dividers[i+1];
    splitSilhouette.push(subpath(current,start,end));
    paramSplitSilhouette.push(subpath(currentParam, start, end));
      }
    }

    /*
     * Now, split at intersections of distinct subpaths.
     */

    for (int j = 0; j < splitSilhouette.length; ++j) {
      path current = splitSilhouette[j];
      path currentParam = paramSplitSilhouette[j];

      real[] splittingTimes = new real[] {0,length(current)};
      for (int k = 0; k < splitSilhouette.length; ++k) {
    if (j == k) continue;
    real[][] times = intersections(current, splitSilhouette[k]);
    for (real[] time : times) {
      real relevantTime = time[0];
      if (.01 < relevantTime && relevantTime < length(current) - .01) splittingTimes.push(relevantTime);
    }
      }
      splittingTimes = sort(splittingTimes);
      for (int i = 0; i + 1 < splittingTimes.length; ++i) {
    real start = splittingTimes[i];
    real end = splittingTimes[i+1];
    real mid = start + ((end-start) / (2+0.1*unitrand()));
    pair theparampoint = point(currentParam, mid);
    int sheets = numSheetsHiding(theparampoint);

    if (sheets == 0 || includePathsBehind) {
      path currentSubpath = subpath(current, start, end);
      addPath(currentSubpath, p=p, onTop=onTop, layer=sheets);
    }

      }
    }
  }

  /*
    Splits a parametrized path along the parametrized silhouette,
    taking [0,1] x [0,1] as the
    fundamental domain.  Could be implemented more efficiently.
  */
  private real[] splitTimes(path thepath) {
    pair min = min(thepath);
    pair max = max(thepath);
    path[] baseknives = paramSilhouette;
    path[] knives;
    for (int u = floor(min.x); u < max.x + .001; ++u) {
      for (int v = floor(min.y); v < max.y + .001; ++v) {
    knives.append(shift(u,v)*baseknives);
      }
    }
    return cutTimes(thepath, knives);
  }

  /*
    Returns the times at which the projection of the given path3 intersects
    the projection of the surface silhouette. This may miss unstable
    intersections that can be detected by the previous method.
  */
  private real[] silhouetteCrossingTimes(path3 thepath, real fuzz = .01) {
    path projectedpath = project(thepath, theProjection, ninterpolate=1);
    real[] crossingTimes = cutTimes(projectedpath, projectedSilhouette);
    if (crossingTimes.length == 0) return crossingTimes;
    real current = 0;
    real[] toReturn = new real[] {0};
    for (real prospective : crossingTimes) {
      if (prospective > current + fuzz
      && prospective < length(thepath) - fuzz) {
    toReturn.push(prospective);
    current = prospective;
      }
    }
    toReturn.push(length(thepath));
    return toReturn;
  }

  void drawSurfacePath(path parampath, pen p=currentpen, bool onTop=true) {
    path[] toDraw;
    real[] crossingTimes = splitTimes(parampath);
    crossingTimes.append(silhouetteCrossingTimes(onSurface(parampath)));
    crossingTimes = condense(crossingTimes);
    for (int i = 0; i+1 < crossingTimes.length; ++i) {
      toDraw.push(subpath(parampath, crossingTimes[i], crossingTimes[i+1]));
    }
    for (path thepath : toDraw) {
      pair midpoint = point(thepath, length(thepath) / (2+.1*unitrand()));
      int sheets = numSheetsHiding(midpoint);
      path path3d = project(onSurface(thepath), theProjection, ninterpolate = 1);
      addPath(path3d, p=p, onTop=onTop, layer=sheets);
    }
  }
}

real unit = 4cm;
unitsize(unit);
triple eye = (10,1,4);
//currentprojection=perspective(2*eye);
currentprojection=orthographic(eye);

surface torus = surface(Circle(c=2Y, r=0.6, normal=X, n=32), c=O, axis=Z, n=32);
torus.ucyclic(true);
torus.vcyclic(true);

SmoothSurface Torus = SmoothSurface(torus);

Torus.drawSilhouette(p=black, includePathsBehind=true);

pair a = (22/40, 3/40);
pair b = (5/40, .5);

path abpathparam(int ucycles, int vcycles) {
  pair bshift = (ucycles, vcycles);
  pair f(real t) {
    return (1-t)*a + t*(b+bshift);
  }
  return graph(f, 0, 1, n=10);
}

real linewidth = 2.3pt;

//Torus.drawSurfacePath(abpathparam(0,0), p=linewidth + red);
Torus.drawSurfacePath(abpathparam(-1,0), p=linewidth + green);
//Torus.drawSurfacePath(abpathparam(1,-1), p=linewidth + red);
Torus.drawSurfacePath(abpathparam(1,0), p=linewidth + green);

pen meshpen = gray(0.6);
for (real u = 0; u < 1; u += 1/40) {
  Torus.drawSurfacePath(graph(new pair(real v) {return (u,v);}, 0,1,n=5), p=meshpen, onTop=false);
}
for (real v = 0; v < 1; v += 1/20) {
  Torus.drawSurfacePath(graph(new pair(real u) {return (u,v);}, 0, 1, n=5), p=meshpen, onTop=false);
}

drawLayeredPaths();

label(project(Torus.point(a.x,a.y)), L="$\phi$", align=W);
//dot(project(Torus.point(b.x,b.y)), L="$b$", align=N);
```

Comment: Number of smooth windings can be chosen in the last two loops : `u+=1/40` and 'v+=1/20`. For question (I) I do not understand "the winding is not very smooth", if it is the green part it is only due to the function's choice. For questions (II) and (III) could you provide the code ?

Comment: @O.G. How to change the `u` and `v` to get the right winding? For my first question, not very smooth means there was a break in the smooth curvature at two points(initial and final), hope it is clear. For last two questions, I would think the same code should work, no? Since I could not find the right parameters, hence unable to provide the code.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can draw such things with Ti*k*Z/pgfplots. This post combines elements from [this gorgeous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715) as well as others that are indicated in the comments.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
% based on 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485833
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485494
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=16cm}
\tikzset{declare function={torusx(\u,\v,\R,\r)=cos(\u)*(\R + \r*cos(\v)); 
torusy(\u,\v,\R,\r)=(\R + \r*cos(\v))*sin(\u);
torusz(\u,\v,\R,\r)=\r*sin(\v);
vcrit1(\u,\th)=atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% first critical v value
vcrit2(\u,\th)=180+atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% second critical v value
vtest(\u,\v,\az,\el)=sin(-vcrit1(\u-\az,\el)+\v);
disc(\th,\R,\r)=((pow(\r,2)-pow(\R,2))*pow(cot(\th),2)+% 
pow(\r,2)*(2+pow(tan(\th),2)))/pow(\R,2);% discriminant
umax(\th,\R,\r)=ifthenelse(disc(\th,\R,\r)>0,asin(sqrt(abs(disc(\th,\R,\r)))),0);
}}
\pgfplotsset{visible stretch/.style={restrict expr to domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-0.05:1.1}},
hidden stretch/.style={restrict expr to 
domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-1.1:0.05}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1.2}
\pgfplotsset{view={35}{60},axis lines=none,}
\matrix{
\begin{axis}[]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
     \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});
    }
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,hidden
    stretch,green!70!black,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(2*x,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(2*x,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(2*x,x,\R,\r)}); 
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,green!70!black,very thick]  
        ({torusx(2*x,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(2*x,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(2*x,x,\R,\r)});     
\end{axis} \\
\begin{axis}[]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
     \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});
    }
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,hidden
    stretch,purple,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(-30,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(-30,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(-30,x,\R,\r)}); 
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,purple,very thick]  
        ({torusx(-30,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(-30,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(-30,x,\R,\r)}); 
\end{axis} \\ 
\begin{axis}[]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
     \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});
    }
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,hidden
    stretch,red,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(x,2*x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,2*x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,2*x,\R,\r)}); 
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,red,very thick]  
        ({torusx(x,2*x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,2*x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,2*x,\R,\r)});     
\end{axis} \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is to reiterate that the curves really wrap around the torus. This uses a smaller opacity for the hidden stretches but is the same code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
% based on 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485833
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485494
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=16cm}
\tikzset{declare function={torusx(\u,\v,\R,\r)=cos(\u)*(\R + \r*cos(\v)); 
torusy(\u,\v,\R,\r)=(\R + \r*cos(\v))*sin(\u);
torusz(\u,\v,\R,\r)=\r*sin(\v);
vcrit1(\u,\th)=atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% first critical v value
vcrit2(\u,\th)=180+atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% second critical v value
vtest(\u,\v,\az,\el)=sin(-vcrit1(\u-\az,\el)+\v);
disc(\th,\R,\r)=((pow(\r,2)-pow(\R,2))*pow(cot(\th),2)+% 
pow(\r,2)*(2+pow(tan(\th),2)))/pow(\R,2);% discriminant
umax(\th,\R,\r)=ifthenelse(disc(\th,\R,\r)>0,asin(sqrt(abs(disc(\th,\R,\r)))),0);
}}
\pgfplotsset{visible stretch/.style={restrict expr to domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-0.05:1.1}},
hidden stretch/.style={restrict expr to 
domain={vtest(atan2(rawy,rawx),%
ifthenelse(veclen(rawx,rawy)>\R,asin(rawz/\r),180-asin(rawz/\r)),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el})}{-1.1:0.05}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1.2}
\pgfplotsset{view={35}{60},axis lines=none,}
\matrix{
\begin{axis}[]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
     \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});
    }
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,opacity=0.6,
        green!70!black,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(2*x,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(2*x,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(2*x,x,\R,\r)}); 
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,green!70!black,very thick]  
        ({torusx(2*x,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(2*x,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(2*x,x,\R,\r)});     
\end{axis} \\
\begin{axis}[]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
     \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});
    }
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,opacity=0.6,
        purple,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(-30,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(-30,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(-30,x,\R,\r)}); 
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,purple,very thick]  
        ({torusx(-30,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(-30,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(-30,x,\R,\r)}); 
\end{axis} \\ 
\begin{axis}[]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
     \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,ultra thin,gray!50]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});
    }
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,opacity=0.6,
        red,very thick,dashed]  
        ({torusx(x,2*x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,2*x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,2*x,\R,\r)}); 
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,10,...,350}  
    {\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:361,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,#1+x/12,\R,\r)});
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible stretch,very
    thin,gray]  
        ({torusx(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(#1,x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(#1,x,\R,\r)});}
    \addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71,visible
    stretch,red,very thick]  
        ({torusx(x,2*x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusy(x,2*x,\R,\r)}, 
        {torusz(x,2*x,\R,\r)});     
\end{axis} \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is a beautiful answer without doubt. Is there a way to get a better look for the toroid? I mean like in the original question, would be very helpful. I guess, we still miss the first plot and the blurriness, instead of dash :)

Comment: @Shamina You can change the line style, the radii and the view angles at will. I changed them a bit to get something more reminiscent of Charles's answer but I really do not know what you like best.

Comment: I think in your plot when the curve is winding(which is shown in dashed) is actually not actually tracing the torus inner surface but just outside one, no? Unlike Charles answer. Where it was blur it actually passing through the inside. However, I think it is doable?

Comment: @Shamina I do not think so.

Comment: Just to be clear: "I do not think so" means that I disagree with the assertion that "it is actually not actually tracing the torus inner surface but just outside one".

Answer (score 5):

We know the parameter equation of a torus, so we can *extract* equations of various curves on it. This is convenient with so called [first-class values](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Ebowman/publications/asyTUG.pdf)'s Asymptote functions. Mathematically, it is as simple as with the function `z=f(x,y)`, we can define

[image]

The number of windings is `d` in the last code.

**1. Vertical circles**

[image]

```
// https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529946/140722
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import graph3;
size(200,0);
currentprojection=orthographic(4,0,2.5,zoom=.9);
real R=2;
real a=.7;
// parameter equation of the torus
triple f(real u,real v) {return (
(R+a*cos(v))*cos(u),
(R+a*cos(v))*sin(u),
a*sin(v)
);}
// more flexibe usage: f(u,v) for f((u,v))
triple f(pair P) {return f(P.x,P.y);}

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2pi,2pi),24,12,Spline);
//pen spen=yellow+opacity(1);
pen spen=yellow+opacity(.5);
//pen spen=invisible;
draw(s,spen,meshpen=gray+.05pt);

typedef triple fvertical(real);
fvertical fv(real u) {
return new triple(real v) {
return f(u,v);
};}

path3 gfv=graph(fv(pi/3),0,2pi,Spline);  
draw(gfv,red+1.5pt);
path3 gfv2=graph(fv(6),0,2pi,Spline);  
draw(gfv2,blue+1.5pt);
```

**2. Horizontal circles**

[image]

```
typedef triple fhorizontal(real);
fhorizontal fh(real v) {
return new triple(real u) {
return f(u,v);
};}

path3 gfh=graph(fh(pi/3),0,2pi,Spline);  
draw(gfh,red+1.5pt);
path3 gfh2=graph(fh(6),0,2pi,Spline);  
draw(gfh2,blue+1.5pt);
```

**3. and various closed curves:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Compare the case of `k=1/3` with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468515/140722).

[image]

```
// various closed curves on the torus
// try k=1/10,1/3,1/2,1,2,3,10
real k=1; label("$k=1$",O);
real d = (k>1) ? k : 1/k;  // number of windings

typedef triple fcurve(real);
fcurve fc(real v) {
return new triple(real u) {
return f(u,v=k*u);
};}

real sA=1;
int nsample=floor(100*d); // should be quite big

path3 gsA=graph(fc(sA),0,2pi*d,nsample,Spline);  
draw(gsA,red+1.5pt);
```